# Why django rest framework return invalid JSON reponse?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I used djangorestframework to generate API, my Serializer as:

```
from rest_framework import serializers


class MarketSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    total_market_cap = serializers.FloatField(read_only=True)
    volume = serializers.FloatField(required=False)
    turnover_rate = serializers.FloatField(required=False)
    pe = serializers.FloatField(required=False)


class MarketOverallSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    # markets = MarketSerializer(many=True)  # A nested list of 'edit' items.
    sh = MarketSerializer()
    sz = MarketSerializer()
    cyb = MarketSerializer()
    zxb = MarketSerializer()
```

My APIView as:

```
import json
from django.shortcuts import render

# Create your views here.
from rest_framework.renderers import JSONRenderer

from rest_framework.views import APIView
from rest_framework.response import Response
from rest_framework import status
from serializers import MarketSerializer, MarketOverallSerializer
from market.models import Market
from market.parse import *


class MarketView(APIView):

    def get(self, request, *args, **kw):
        # Process any get params that you may need
        # If you don't need to process get params,
        # you can skip this part
        market = market_overall()
        serializer = MarketOverallSerializer(market)
        content = JSONRenderer().render(serializer.data)
        print '**********content:{}'.format(content)
        response = Response(content, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)

        return response
```

I get JSON response as:

```
"{\"sh\":{\"total_market_cap\":262143.47,\"volume\":25240015.73,\"turnover_rate\":0.84,\"pe\":15.8},\"sz\":{\"total_market_cap\":0.0,\"volume\":0.0,\"turnover_rate\":0.0,\"pe\":0.0},\"cyb\":null,\"zxb\":null}"
```

Why the generated response is not valid JSON output, with so many "\" characters?

Comment: response = Response(json.loads(content), status=status.HTTP_200_OK), but why this worked?

Answer (score 2):

The reason is that the default renderer in DRF is json (ref: http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/renderers/#setting-the-renderers).

So every time you use DRF's `Response` you should directly pass the dict instead of rendered json.

In your case by rendering json once and then again (by using `Response`) the json build-in module escapes special characters and treats it as single string (that's why `json.loads()` gives back proper json)

So the way to fix it is either:

- don't use `JSONRenderer`, just pass the dict directly to `Response`
- remove `JSONRenderer` and then exclusively tell `Response` to use `text/html` as content type.